# Visual Basic - Random Number Generator using Array and For Loop

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I need assistance with creating an elementary array in VB.NET.

**The objective is to load a random number into each array location and then display the contents of the array. There are 100 index values from 1 to 100.**

Here is what I have so far:

```
    Dim Output As String
    Dim RandomNumber As Integer
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim NumberArray(101) As Integer

    NumberArray(n) = RandomNumber

    For n = 1 To 100
        Randomize()
        RandomNumber = Int(Rnd() * 100) + 1
    Next

    Output = Output & "Index #" & n & vbTab & NumberArray(n) & vbCrLf

    TextBox1.Text = Output
```

The output I am receiving is:

Index #101           0

I cannot figure out how to output the entire list of arrays.

Comment: This is also a good example why you should declare your variables only within the scope you wish to use them. As you see, you expect N to change outside of your loop. Had you declared N: "For N As Integer", then  on your next lines outside of your For-Next statement, the designer would have reminded you that you were attempting to use a variable outside of it's scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using RANDOM **Try this:**

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Option Infer Off
Public Class Form1
    Dim random As New Random(Now.Millisecond)
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim array() As Integer = {}

        For I As Integer = 1 To 100
            ReDim Preserve array(I - 1)
            array(I - 1) = random.Next(0, 101)
        Next
        MsgBox(arrToStr(array))
    End Sub
    Function arrToStr(arr As Integer()) As String
        Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
        For i As Integer = 0 To UBound(arr)
            If i = UBound(arr) Then
                sb.Append(arr(i).ToString)
            Else
                sb.Append(arr(i).ToString & ", ")
            End If
        Next
        Return sb.ToString
    End Function
End Class
```

**In your style:**

```
Randomize()
Dim Output As String = String.Empty
Dim NumberArray(99) As Integer
For n As Integer = 0 To 99
    Dim RandomNumber As Integer = CInt(Int(Rnd() * 100) + 1)
    NumberArray(n) = RandomNumber
    Output &= "Index #" & n.ToString & Space(4) & NumberArray(n) & vbCrLf
Next
TextBox1.Text = Output
```

Answer (score 0):

All your loop is doing is generating random numbers, and assigning them to a variable, which then gets overwritten in the next iteration. You need to move the array assignment and output string concatenation to inside the loop.

```
Dim Output As String = ""
Dim RandomNumber As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim NumberArray(101) As Integer

For n = 1 To 100
    Randomize()
    RandomNumber = Int(Rnd() * 100) + 1

    NumberArray(n) = RandomNumber
    Output &= "Index #" & n.ToString & vbTab & NumberArray(n).ToString & vbCrLf
Next

TextBox1.Text = Output
```

Please note that the code above is not 'ideal.' I specifically wrote it this way to retain as much of the asker's original code for clarity.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is there any other way to do this without replacing n with n.ToString?

Comment: FYI: The zero'th element of the array will not be assigned a random number.

Comment: You can keep it as you had it, if you prefer. `.ToString` is simply converting the Integer value of `n` to a String type suitable for concatenating into the output. With `Option Strict` off, there isn't really a difference.

Comment: As justin said, but Option Strict Off is a bad idea, and typically only set to off in com interop/vb6 porting situations. Option Strict On is Best practice, so it's better to get into that habit. That being said, use either .ToString or CStr.

Comment: @Paul I see what you are saying. How can I assign it in the range of 1-100? I appreciate your code, but it changes my style almost entirely.

Comment: @Afg You would declare `NumberArray(99)` and instead loop `For n As Integer = 0 To 99`.

Comment: @Justin, I'm sorry, but this is not working. It causes a index out of bounds error. I tried changing the random function to Int(Rnd() * 99) but that does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

You could cut down on code, as follows:

```
Dim Output As String =""
Dim i As Integer
Randomize(Timer.Now)
For i = 1 To 100
    Output = Output & i & vbTab & (Rnd() * 99) + 1 & vbCrLf
Next
TextBox1.Text = Output
```

The random numbers will be unreliable, since the default rn generator is not that good in terms of periodicity.